# What is the difference between Google Chrome and Chronium

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

I noticed that Google Chrome was developed partly by the "Chromium Project". I also found out that there was a separate browser named Chromium. I tried it out and I found that it was the same as Google Chrome but I am quite sure that there is a difference between them. Does anyone know what it is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google released most of the Chrome source code as an open source project called Chromium. The Chromium browser is compiled from that Chromium project source code.

The Chrome browser released by Google uses most of the same source code, but Google has added proprietary changes such as a DRM model and codec support for h264 video.

A similar situation exists with Firefox vs Iceweasel browsers; one is a version of the former to allow for broader and less restricted licensing.

Comment: Iceweasel is different – it's not an official Mozilla project, but a third-party fork for branding reasons. (The source code of Firefox is free, but the name "Firefox" is a trademark.)

Comment: @grawity Chromium not the product but the project creating source code that works on its own as its own product and being named Chromium instead of Chrome is no more official than Iceweasel. I really don't get your point. It is substantively different in that Chromium is intended to be a development bed for which Chrome (as a project not as a product) is based. But as a product its pretty much exactly like Iceweasel.